# SWFAddress 2.2 isn't responding to specific URLs

Tags: actionscript-2, swfaddress

I am implementing SWFAddress into a Flash movie, and while my navigation is setting the links correctly, when I type in a specific URL, it doesn't seem to communicate with the browser at all. Am I missing a listener or something?

http://client.deicreative.com/test/TBB/

This class talks to my navigation class:

```
import SWFAddress.as;

class code.RunSWFAddress {

public function RunSWFAddress(){
    init();
}
private function init() {
    var scope = this;

    SWFAddress.setStrict(false);
    SWFAddress.onChange = function() {
        var value = SWFAddress.getValue();
        var path = SWFAddress.getPath();
        var id = SWFAddress.getParameter('id');
        if (code.PageContent.getInstance().xmlVar1.getBytesLoaded() == code.PageContent.getInstance().xmlVar1.getBytesTotal()){

            if(SWFAddress.getValue() == '/' || SWFAddress.getValue() == '') {
                code.Navigation.getInstance().showPage(0);

            } else {
                for(var i:Number = 0; i<code.Startup.getInstance().numPages; i++){
                    if(SWFAddress.getValue() == code.Startup.getInstance().page_arr[i][0]){

                        code.Navigation.getInstance().showPage(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var title = 'The Broadway Building';    
        var names = SWFAddress.getPathNames();
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            title += ' | ' + names[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + names[i].substr(1);
        }
        var id = SWFAddress.getParameter('id');
        if (id != '') {
            title += ' | ' + id; 
        }
        SWFAddress.setTitle(title);
    }

}

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the id attribute in my swfobject embed. Works now! :)